# How to pass $(this) properly in click jQuery function

Tags: jquery, click, this

I am trying to make a tictactoe project in jQuery and I am having a major problem...

The tiles are in `<td>` tags and I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the the tile, it calls the "marked" function.

If we now look into the "marked" function, `$(this)` is intended to be the `<td>` node that the function was called from.

However, it wasn't doing anything so I checked the console and apparently `$(this)` was containing the DOM Window object.

Is there anyway I can send the right kind of `$(this)` to the "marked" function?

Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var TURN_X = false;
    var TURN_O = true;

    var turn = false;  // this is to see whos turn it is.

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var listCells = $.makeArray($("td"));
        $("td").click(function(){marked(listCells)});   //THIS IS WHERE I HAVE PROBLEMS
        return false;
    });

    function marked(arr)
    {
        console.log($(this));  // THIS CONSOLE LOG RETURNS "DOM Window"
        $(this).addClass("marked");

        if(turn == TURN_X)
        {
        this.innerHTML = "X";
        turn = false;
        }
        else
        this.innerHTML = "O";

        var tileNum = $(this).attr("id");
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to pass in the entire array (i.e. `listCells`) or just the table cell you clicked on? - If just the td you clicked on you could use `$("td").click(function(){marked($(this))});` in your click event..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You code does not follow the right principles.

```
$(function(){
    var TURN_X = "X",
        TURN_O = "O", 
        turn   = TURN_O,
        $listCells = $("td");

    function marked() {        // define event handler
        var $this   = $(this),
            tileNum = $this.attr("id");

        if ( !($this.hasClass("marked") ) {
            $this.addClass("marked").text(turn);
            turn = (turn == TURN_X) ? TURN_O : TURN_X;
        }
    }

    $listCells.click(marked);  // attach event handler
});
```

1. Wrap everything in the document.ready function. Avoid global variables wherever possible.
2. Make use of the fact that jQuery manages `this` for you. `this` will always be what you expect if you pass callback functions directly instead of calling them yourself.

Comment: This is just a side question but I was just curious why wrapping everything in the ready function and avoiding global variables are good coding habit.

Comment: Also, I am trying to create an array of "td" tags present. From my understanding, the selector operation $("td") returns nodeList, not array. Will assigning $("td") to a jquery object $listCells convert the nodelist into an array?

Comment: @wayfare **a)** Polluting the global namespace has side effects, most prominently variables from different parts of a project that overwrite each other. As long as a project is small, this does not happen. When a project grows, this can introduce annoying and hard-to-find bugs. Apart from that it is bad style to transport state through global variables. **b)** A jQuery object *is* an array. No need to convert it. `$('td')` returns an array of `<td>` nodes. Note that I use `$varname` to denote a variable that contains a jQuery object - it's a convention.

Answer (score 15):

Send the element which fire the event to the function like that:

```
$("td").click(function(){
        marked($(this));
        return false;
    });
```

and in the function:

```
function marked(td)
{
     console.log($(td));  
     $(td).addClass("marked");
     //....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

More simply, use bind :

```
$(".detailsbox").click(function(evt){
   test.bind($(this))();
});
function test()
{
   var $this = $(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("td").click(function(event){
    marked(listCells, $(this));
});
```

Then:

```
function marked(arr, sel) {
    console.log($(this));
    sel.addClass("marked");

    if(turn == TURN_X) {
        this.innerHTML = "X";
        turn = false;
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = "O";
    }
    var tileNum = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    var listCells = $.makeArray($("td"));
    $("td").click(function(){marked($(this),listCells)});  
});



function marked(o,arr)
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `call` method to specify the scope for the function:

```
$("td").click(function(){ marked.call(this, listCells); });
```

Now the `marked` function can access the clicked element using the `this` keyword.

Comment: He is using mix of `$(this)` and `this` inside his function :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$(this)` to your function:

```
$("td").click(function(){ marked(listCells, $(this))} );
```

And modify your function like this:

```
function marked(arr, that)
{
  that.addClass("marked");

  if(turn == TURN_X)
  {
    that.innerHTML = "X";
    turn = false;
  }
  else
    that.innerHTML = "O";

  var tileNum = that.attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var TURN_X = false,
        TURN_O = true,
        turn = false,
        listCells = $.makeArray($("td"));

    $("td").click(function() {
        marked(listCells, this)
    });

    function marked(arr, self) {
        $(self).addClass("marked");

        if(turn == TURN_X) {
            self.innerHTML = "X";
            turn = false;
        }else{
            self.innerHTML = "O";
            var tileNum = self.id;
        }
    }
});
```