# jQuery Toggle closest info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have the following html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="group">
      <div class="label">
         <li class="interrogation">?</li>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="message"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="group">
      <div class="label">
         <li class="interrogation">?</li>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

This is my `ns.init` function:

```
ns.init = function() {
    $(".message").hide();
    $(".interrogation").click(function(){
        $(".interrogation").closest(".group").parent().find(".message").toggle();
    });
}
```

The current code works but it toggles all the messages on the page when I click one of them. How can I make it toggle only the message that is exactly after the question mark ?

Comment: use `$(this).closest()` instead of `('.interrogation').closest()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you use `$(".interrogation")` selector in your function. This selects **all** elements with that class in the document. Use `$(this)` to only have the element that you clicked on as reference for your selector.

**Here is a working fiddle:**

```js
$(function() {
    $(".message").hide();
    $(".interrogation").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".group").parent().find(".message").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="group">
              <div class="label">
                  <li class="interrogation">?</li>
              </div>
          </div>
        <div class="message">Message1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="group">
              <div class="label">
                  <li class="interrogation">?</li>
              </div>
          </div>
  <div class="message">Message2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question has some details on the use of `this` in jQuery click function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563479/how-to-pass-this-properly-in-click-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/denquhL1/1/

```js
$('.interrogation').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div.group').next('div.message').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.message{
  display: none;
}

.interrogation {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="group">
      <div class="label">
         <li class="interrogation">?</li>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="message">Message 1</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="group">
      <div class="label">
         <li class="interrogation">?</li>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="message">Message 2</div>
</div>
```

`Onclick` of `.interrogation` class, it will traverse to closest `.group` container, then it will look for next `.message` container.

Instead of `toggle`, I've used `slideToggle` with animation.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var ns = {};
ns.init = function() {
  $(".message").hide()
  $(".interrogation").click(function() {
    var commonParent = $(this).closest(".col-md-12");
    commonParent.find(".message").toggle();
  });
}
ns.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="label">
      <li class="interrogation">?</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">Msg 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="label">
      <li class="interrogation">?</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">Msg 2</div>
</div>
```